# I am trying to convert dollars to pounds using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to convert mile to Km using jQuery but I can't seem to do it. The value from the text box isn't being identified.

Comment: What you expected in `myMoney` variable?

Comment: try with parseInt() --> var newBalance = parseInt(value) * current    More info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Please don't remove the code from the question. Now it looks like a question that would be impossible to answer, and it's pretty much useless for anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the value when the page loads and the text field is empty. Even if you change the text field, the variable still contains that value that you got when the page loaded.

Get the value when you are going to use it:

```
function showMoney(current, curr){
  var value = $("#text").val();
  var newBalance = value * current;
  $(".money").html(" you have travelled " + newBalance + " " + curr);
}
```